# Организация фрагментов приложения android

Tags: android, android-fragment, backstack

В общем понадобилась реализовать задачу без использования PageView, где эта задача решалась бы куда проще. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот моя структура приложения. есть корневой FrameView, куда подменяю нужнный мне фрагмент. Все бы ничего, если бы три главных фрагмента не переключались боттом навигейшн. Проблема в том, что если находясь на дочернем фрагменте третьего уровня переключиться на другой фрагмент из боттом навигейшн, то сыпется вся логика backStack фрагментов. Ложку дегтя еще добавляет дополнительный фрагмент, который вызывается из бокового меню. Прошу совета или подсказки как лучше организовать переключение между фрагментами. если при переключении фрагмента по нижней менюхе вызывать getFragmentManager.beginTracsacion().remove(...).commit() и гасить все остальные фрагменты, стек переходов все равно не обнуляется и даже переход на нулевой фрагмент с флагом FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE не дает нужного результата. в общем голова пухнет уже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько советов о том как я решал подобную проблему:

1) Я изрядно помучившись создал собственный стек фрагментов, типа:

```
class SimpleFragmentStack {
    //содержит в себе теги фрагментов
    Stack<String> fragmentStack;
    //добавить фрагмент
    public void push(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(fragmentContainer,
              fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
        fragmentStack.push(tag);        
    }              
     //заменить фрагмент на верхушке стека
    public void replace(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment, String tag); 
    //вытолкнуть верхний фрагмент
    public Fragment pop();
    //извлечь фрагмент из верхушки (текущий)
    public Fragment peek();
    //очистить стек
    public void reset();
    public int size() {return fragmentStack.size();}
}
```

Смысл в том, что этот ручной манагер фрагментов как бы дублирует собственный стек фрагментов системы, но при этом у меня всегда есть полный контроль над тем где и какой фрагмент находится, любой фрагмент можно вытащить по его тегу, который хранится в моем стеке тегов. Ну и кстати, отлаживать так тоже намного проще.

2) Вторая история связана с тем, что когда у вас есть вложенные фрагменты, чтобы достучаться до вложенного фрагмента, вам нужно использовать метод [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) -работает с API 17

Comment: идея интересная.. сейчас тоже подобие ручного управления стека, только в более колхозном виде. getChildFragmentManager() мне не подходит, так как минимальная API должна быть 16... у меня сейчас возникла мысль для корневых фрагментов использовать getFragmentManager, а для дочерних getSupportFragmentManager, дабы отделить мух от котлет и безболезненно убивать без боязни поломать стек. но пока не углублялся в дебри библиотеки поддержки... если там тоже используется родительский контекст, то это еще одни грабли, но менее глобальные